# T-SQL Can't disable or enable windows Scheduled task

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

If I try from SQL to enable or disable windows Scheduled task:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'schtasks /change /TN MyTaskName /ENABLE'
```

or

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'schtasks /change /TN MyTaskName /DISABLE'
```

I got this error message:

> ERROR: The specified task name "MyTaskName" does not exist in the system.

Although I could use /QUERY parameter and get Task list:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'schtasks /query'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 possible problems:

1. You have to put with task name exactly path to Task:

   ```
   EXEC xp_cmdshell 'schtasks /change /TN MyFolderName\MyTaskName /ENABLE'
   ```
2. Account that started SQL server service (in Services) should have permissions for changing Scheduled task properties. For example change account to Local system, restart SQL server service and check if you can now Enable/Disable Scheduled task.